# English/Arabic Encoding Problem

Tags: php, encoding

I am designing a web page this web page should support

English and Arabic languages

my problem is : Arabic characters doesn't appear in its way

it appears some thing like that "Ø£Ù‡Ù„Ø§Ù‹ ÙŠØ§ Ù…Ø¹Ù„Ù… "

I have tried to change the encoding of this page with the following tag

```
<META CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1256" HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type">
```

but it didn't work and I tried the "utf-8" but it doesn't work either?

thanks for reading my question

Comment: What IDE or editor are you using to create these pages? It may not be encoding the files properly.

Comment: Zend Framework I think you know about it

Answer (score 2):

You need to change more than that : ideally, everything should be set to, or encoded in, UTF-8 :

- the source code of your scripts / pages

  - configuring your IDE / editor to encode in UTF-8 by default might be a good idea, here
- the data in your database -- *if you are using one*

  - the connection between PHP and your DB
- the meta tag, like you did -- eventually ; not sure it's that usefull, actually
- the HTTP Content-type header *(see point 14.17 or [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), for instance)*
- well, everything.

For the last part, this should do the trick, in PHP :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

*(You might need to adjust it, depending on your... content-type ^^ )*

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is most certainly UTF-8.

As good basic reading, I recommend [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

If you want more detailed help here, you will have to describe what exactly you do: Where your data comes from, whether you use a CMS and so on. (Update: @Pascal Martin already mentioned all the important points).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bulletproof way I use. First instruct PHP to deal with UTF8 all the way:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding('output_encoding',   'UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Then double-check that the browser knows that we're using the UTF scheme:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your page's encoding to UTF-8 using the `meta` method and make sure your files are saved in UTF-8 (in your editor, check that the encoding used is UTF-8).

Comment: I checked it for more than one times
The source code is utf-8
the page encoding is utf-8 also 
but no result !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try add this `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to your .htacess file

Answer (score 0):

you need to save php file with encoding (UTF-8).